# "Los otros días" o "El otro día"

Tags: gramática

Tengo un debate con mi novia.  Yo dije "Los otros días, yo fui a una corrida de toros en La Arena Mexico.".  No sabiendo qué dia fue.  Ella dice que lo correcto es decir "El otro día, yo fui a una corrida de toros en La Arena Mexico."  ¿Son ambos correctos?

¿En qué contexto es correcto decir "los otros días"?

Answer (score 5):

Dices "El otro día" si te refieres a algo que ocurrió (una o varias veces) un único día pasado, y "Los otros días" si te refieres a algo que ocurrió en varios días pasados.

Si fuiste a una corrida, fue "el otro día".

Si fuiste a varias corridas en días distintos, fue "los otros días". No hay discordancia de número porque fuiste a ver una corrida cada día.

Por favor ten en cuenta que "el otro día" es una frase común en España, mientras que "los otros días" es una frase rara.

Comment: De este lado es muy comun los otros dias

Comment: @EmilioGort Editado para referirme a España.

Comment: @EmilioGort ¿Dónde sí se dice los *otros días*? Quizá valga mucho la pena tu respuesta, pues supongo que lo que busca el OP es bajo qué condiciones es válida la expresión.

Comment: Por lo menos en Cuba, Colombia y Miami, y se usa indistintamente

Comment: Sin embargo, eso no significa que eso sea una construcción gramatical válida para el significado que se desea. Es sabido que en ninguna región del mundo se habla totalmente bien un idioma.

Comment: @El_Mochiq correcto, aunque en el español exista una academia y haya cosas que no esten reguladas, en algunas regiones el uso de frases es tan comun, que lo que esta regulado en la academia podria no ser lo comun y viseversa

Comment: En Colombia no he escuchado _los otros días_.  No me suena natural, salvo, si acaso, el uso presentado por @makeMonday

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón preguntale a la gente de Barranquilla, Colombia cada departamento es como un pais distinto.

Answer (score 3):

En España, lo correcto es decir `el otro día` siempre. No usamos nada parecido a `los otros días`, a no ser que digas algo como: `Los primeros días fuimos a pasear, los otros días fuimos a correr`. Pero tiene un significado más como de `el resto de los días`.